# Tracing a MotionEvent in a ViewGroup

Tags: android, view, trace, touch-event, viewgroup

I have a class extends `ViewGroup` and want to get every `MotionEvent` from it. So far I have this:

```
class TestViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
     public TestViewGroup(Context context) {
         super(context);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         Log.d("TestViewGroup", "X: " + (int)event.getX() + " Y: " + (int)event.getY());
         return true;
     }
 }
```

The `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method is able to capture a `MotionEvent` every time I place my finger on the screen. But if I move my finger around the screen while my finger is still down, it won't continue to trace the coordinates of my finger. I know that in a class that extends a `View`, it is possible to keep tracing the finger as it moves through the `View`. I'm just wondering how it is possible to apply the same idea to a `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a very simple ViewGroup class and copied your code, the onTouchEvent worked fine

The only thing I did differently was implement all of the constructors, though in general I would also call the super for the onTochEvent class that did not seem to make a difference.

So I am wondering if there is any code/xml you are leaving out that might make a difference?

Captures all touch events in emulator and on device, pretty much just like yours with the exception of the constructors.

```
public class customViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    public customViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context,null,0);
   }

    public customViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs,0);

    }

    public customViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("bThere", "X: " + (int)event.getX() + " Y: " + (int)event.getY());
        return true;//super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Comment: You know, you're right, its nothing to do with View or ViewGroup, it's actually got to do with how I'm integrating it I think. I'm trying to put the ViewGroup into the system's WindowManager so it can stay persistent on a system overlay (basically show a view no matter what activity is on top). Do you know if adding a View to the WindowManager would affect how the touch events are passed to it?

Comment: @AeroDroid ... sounds like an interesting thing to do, I would suggest opening another question and re-phrasing, also add some code.  You might also try @Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {} as an alternative since it seems to be a bit more robust in getting events, you will need to add some code though

Comment: Actually I just opened a new question a while ago, here please take a look at it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725636/getting-all-motionevents-with-windowmanager-layoutparams-flag-watch-outside-touch).

Answer (score -1):

you should add `viewGroup.setClickable(true);` to make sure the view can receive more touchevent.