# Getting all MotionEvents with WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH

Tags: android, view, action, flags, layoutparams

My question refers directly to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4481226/394933). The answer to that question shows how one can create a `ViewGroup`, embed it inside a `WindowManager`, and allow the `WindowManager` to catch `MotionEvent`s through `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`. `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` is the flag that allows this this `ViewGroup` to receive `MotionEvent`s. However, according to documentation, this flag

> ...will not receive the full down/move/up gesture

I want to know if there's a work-around or a way so that I can get all touch events including down, move, and up. A proof of concept is in the app [Wave Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobilemerit.wavelauncher&feature=search_result) which uses the same concept but is able to receive more than just a single `ACTION_OUTSIDE` event.

Comment: here i too facing the same problem, don know wat to do.

Comment: I've actually tried emailing a couple of the developers who have apps that similar things but none of them would get back to me or provide me with an answer.

Comment: I Googled a lot but unable to find the solution.

Comment: Same here, I've Googled pretty much every possible keyword and I end up getting the same things over and over.

Answer (score 3):

No you can not, and that is very much by design.

Wave Launcher doesn't do this, it has a UI element where you start your touch gesture and then as with standard even dispatching all touch events are delivered to the window of the first down point until the final up.

Comment: Would you perhaps know how this is done, specifically? Not just in terms of a concept?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I've stumbled across it while trying to accomplish something similar. I've also found this, hopefully it is helpful to someone: http://www.section465.com/code_OverlayView/

> To create an overlay view, when setting up the LayoutParams you need
>   to set the type to TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY and use the flag
>   FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH. This presents a problem because as the
>   Android documentation states: "you will not receive the full
>   down/move/up gesture, only the location of the first down as an
>   ACTION_OUTSIDE." In order to receive the full array of touch events
>   you need to use the TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT type, but this causes the
>   overlay to take over the screen and stop interaction with other
>   elements. The solution is to use both TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY and
>   TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT and switch between them by changing the type of the
>   LayoutParams as needed.